# How to detect all types of bot in Magento?

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to detect all types of bot in my site.

**Is there any code in magento to detect bots?**

Comment: you can look in your access log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can install from git hub by using composer

https://github.com/JayBizzle/Crawler-Detect

Install by composer

```
composer require jaybizzle/crawler-detect 1.*
```

inject Jaybizzle\CrawlerDetect\CrawlerDetect in your constructor